# Pagination work strange

Tags: php, pagination

I do not know the script works, the problem is - if I delete or add records, or will change $query .= "WHERE visible = 1, for example, I will delete 5 records  it shows me something like this
[image]

paginator not see the deleted records, if refresh firefox `http://localhost/dwwithphp/public/admin/list_photos_5.php?s=40&p=11&sort=ln` nothing happens when I refresh `http://localhost/dwwithphp/public/admin/list_photos_5.php` then sees the changes

after refresh `/admin/list_photos_5.php`
[image]

**pagination work like that or am I doing something wrong?**

```
<?php
//1. database connect
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "3edcvfr4";
$dbname = "dw_bookstore";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

//connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//change utf8
if (!mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
} else {
    //printf("set na: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($connection));
}
?>
<?php
// Number of records to show per page:
$display = 5;

// Determine how many pages there are...
if (isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])) { // Already been determined.

    $pages = $_GET['p'];

    } else { // Need to determine.

    // Determine how many pages there are...
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM photographs";
    $result = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $records = $row[0];

    // Calculate the number of pages...
    if ($records > $display) { // More than 1 page.
        $pages = ceil ($records/$display);
    } else {
        $pages = 1;
    }

} // End of p IF.


// Determine where in the database to start returning results...
if (isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['s'])) {
    $start = $_GET['s'];
} else {
    $start = 0;
}

// Determine the sort...
// Default is by id.
$sort = (isset($_GET['sort'])) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'rd';
// Determine the sorting order:
switch ($sort) {
    case 'ln':
        $order_by = 'filename ASC';
        break;
    case 'fn':
        $order_by = 'size ASC';
        break;
    case 'rd':
        $order_by = 'nazwa ASC';
        break;
    default:
        $order_by = 'id ASC';
        $sort = 'rd';
        break;
}

// Make the query:
    $query  = "SELECT id, filename, size, type, nazwa, kod "; 
    $query .= "FROM photographs "; 
    $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY $order_by LIMIT $start, $display ";     
    $result = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);

?>
<?php
    // 2. Perform database query
    $query2  = "SELECT * ";
    $query2 .= "FROM photographs ";
    $query2 .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
    $query2 .= "ORDER BY nazwa ASC ";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
    // Test if there was a query error
    if (!$result2) {
        die("Database query failed.");
    }


?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>List_n01</title>
<link href="../../stylesheets/main_2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <h2>Cennik: Panel Administracyjny</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="mainContent">
  <h1>Graphic Design</h1>
  <?php

  // Count the number of returned rows:
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

if ($num > 0) { // If it ran OK, display the records.
    // Print how many rows there are:
    echo "<p>W bazie znajduje się $num pozycji.</p>\n"; ?>

    <table id="article">
          <caption></caption>
          <colgroup>
          </colgroup>
          <tr>
                <th><a href="list_photos_5.php?sort=ln">id</a></th>
                <th>filename</th>
                <th>size</th>
                <th>type<a href="list_photos_5.php?sort=fn">Nazwa:</a></th>
                <th>name</th>


          </tr>

    <?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        echo '<tr>
        <td align="left">' . $row['id'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['filename'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['size'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['type'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['nazwa'] . '</td>
    </tr>
    ';
} // End of WHILE loop.

echo '</table>';
?>
    <?php
    // 4. Release returned data
     mysqli_free_result($result);   

} else { // If no records were returned.
    echo '<p class="error">There are currently no rows.</p>';

}

?>
<?php
// Make the links to other pages, if necessary.
if ($pages > 1) {

    echo '<br /><p>';
    $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

    // If it's not the first page, make a Previous button:
    if ($current_page != 1) {
        echo '<a href="list_photos_5.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Previous</a> ';
    }

    // Make all the numbered pages:
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {    
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            $distance = $current_page - $i;
            if (abs($distance) < 5){
                echo '<a href="list_photos_5.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
            } 
        } else {
            echo $i . ' ';
        }
    } // End of FOR loop

    // If it's not the last page, make a Next button:
    if ($current_page != $pages) {
        echo '<a href="list_photos_5.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Next</a>';
    }

    echo '</p>'; // Close the paragraph.

} // End of links section.
?>

  </div>

  <div id="footer">
<p>Copyright <?php echo date("Y",  time()); ?>, Unixlab</p></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
  // 5. Close database connection
  mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: I think problem in your url.When you deleted the records and after deleted the records what you make the url.I think you use same url.Before and after deleting records.s=40 and p =11

Comment: when you deleted the records change the value of s and p in your url

Answer (score 0):

This is your culprit:

// Determine how many pages there are...
if (isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])) { // Already been determined.

```
$pages = $_GET['p'];
```

Basically you are using previously set pagecounts. Just rerun the number of pages every time the page loads, or accept that when updates happen to the database, some users may not directly see the new pagecount.